# Nib/Xib not shown in interface bulider

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, xib

While developing a navigation based application from scratch, I added some new uisubview Controller files to my project by the name myview.m, myview.h and myview.xib. After saving it, when i switched to interface builder to carry out linking task but the xib file was not shown by the interface bulider.

I restarted both the applications to fix it, but it didn't work. Please suggest me how to resolve the issue because i can't proceed further.

MAC OSX: 10.6
XCode: 3.2.6

One of the similar issues I faced earlier was that the methods added to .h files were not visible in interface builder, which I resolved by making the interface builder reading the .h file externally from file menu.

but I was unable to resolve the issue with the xib file. Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: just delete that myview.xib file.add new file-> select user interface->select View. name it as myview. click that xib file-> select the file's owner and the class name as myview in inspector window.

Comment: it is very unclear what you are trying to achieve. is `myview` a `UIView` subclass or a `UIViewController` subclass? are you trying to add it to a XIB file for another `UIViewController`? or to a storyboard? or something else?

Comment: @Tark sir, My aim is to develop a navigation based application. I prefer to develop it from scratch because the default navigation based project includes table view as home screen, which doesnot suit my requirements So I chose window based application and then added new file that is uisubview controller along with xib file. When i switched to interface builder to attach the xib file to **Main Window** then i didnt find the xib file in the inspector window to carry out the linking..

Comment: i resolved the issue by following the suggestion of @MuditBajpai and created the xib files externally from interface builder.. the link helped me a lot [link]http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/02/28/window-based-app-tutorial-part-1-add-a-uinavigationcontroller/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its ok if it is not shown by default. Simply mention the name over there. It works.